# Creating pdf, svg and hi-res img in Java - Cairo? Other solutions?

Tags: java, pdf, svg, cairo

I want to create pdf, svg and hi-res antialiased img using Java.

The java-gnome project (http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/4.0/) contains cairo
bindings, but there are problems using it on xp because of the multithreaded gtk 
incompatibilities with xp...

Any of you guys that have successfully been using java-gnome cairo stuff compiling on xp?
Are there other java solutions/libraries that can handle the same stuff with the same
quality?

Answer (score 2):

The Apache Batik toolkit is an implementation of SVG built on the Java 2D library: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/

One can say objectively that it is one of the best, most complete implementations of SVG: http://www.codedread.com/svg-support.php (it's at the bottom of the table)

You can use it to render PDFs (as well as PNGs and other bitmap formats) using the SVG rasterizer component: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html

I can also say from personal experience that it has very easy to work with, although I haven't used it very much on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, echo-flow! Batik seems great for svg, but still a roundtrip for bitmaps and pdfs compared to cairo...

Comment: What I was suggesting is that you start with SVG as your source format, and then export to the other formats. Whether this is the best approach is very dependent on the kind of content you're attempting to create. If you provide more info on this, I may be able to point you to further resources.

Comment: Hi again, echo-flow! Downloading and trying Batik 1.7 source code gives me errors because org.w3c packages are missing (org.w3c.svg.*, org.w3c.css.* etc. Do you know where to get them?